# Changing the suffix according to the figure number

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, languages

In Turkish (and possibly in other similar languages), there are suffixes that change corresponding to the word they are applied. This also holds for the numbers.

For example,

```
in Figure \ref{fig1}
```

is written in Turkish as follows:

```
Şekil \ref{fig1}'de
```

The problem here is that the suffix `"de"` should change according to the number rendered before it. It should be like

```
1'de, 2'de, 3'te, 4'te, 5'te, 6'da, ..., 60'ta, ..., 70'te, ...
```

I don't like to check the suffixes manually after finishing the paper. This also happens for the other cross-references like equations.

How can I do this in LaTeX?

**Edit**: I'm adding the complete rule as @egreg asks. The determining numbers are as follows:

```
0'da
1'de
2'de
3'te
4'te
5'te
6'da
7'de
8'de
9'da
10'da
20'de
30'da
40'da
50'de
60'ta
70'te
80'de
90'da
100'de
1000'de
1000000'da
1000000000'da
```

For all the others, the number at the end determines the suffix if it is non-zero. For example

```
1234'te  (4'te)
303'te (3'te)
```

But, if there's a zero at the end and the number is not zero, then the right-most non-zero digit determines the result:

```
230'da (30'da)
200'de (100'de)
4000'de (1000'de)
40000'de (1000'de)
400000'de (1000'de)
4000000'da (1000000'da)
```

The suffix is determined by the last read word. For example 40000 is read as "kırk bin" and it becomes "40000'de". It is the same as "1000'de" which is read as "binde".

Comment: Can you spell out the complete rule?

Comment: are these suffixes like the ordinal suffixes in english -- 1st 2nd 3rd 4th ... 11th ... 21st (and so on)?

Comment: Yes, they are like the ordinal suffixes in English.

Comment: I've added the full spec.

Comment: The package `fmtcount` can be of use. I have to go now, but later (3 hours maybe) I'll prepare an `.def` file for this Turkish rules (unless someone else does so).

Comment: @petrichor Just to be sure: should it be "300'de" or "300'te"?

Comment: It will be 300'de since it is read as "üç yüzde" as in "yüzde".

Comment: @egreg can u make this for `\cite` too please? :)

Comment: @WhoCares Not without a new question with the full specification of the suffixes to be used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a possible implementation using LaTeX3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{multicol} % only needed for the test

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\turkishref}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\ref*{#2}}{\ref{#2}}
  \turksuf_suffix_get:n { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__turksuf_ref_seq
\tl_new:N \l__turksuf_ref_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \turksuf_suffix_get:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l__turksuf_ref_seq { . } { \getrefnumber { #1 } }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__turksuf_ref_seq \l__turksuf_ref_tl
  \turksuf_suffix:V \l__turksuf_ref_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }

\NewDocumentCommand{\turkishsuffix}{m}
 {
  \turksuf_suffix:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \turksuf_suffix:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 == 0 } { 'da } { \turksuf_nonzero:n { #1 } }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \turksuf_nonzero:n #1
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {1}{'de}
    {2}{'de}
    {3}{'te}
    {4}{'te}
    {5}{'te}
    {6}{'da}
    {7}{'de}
    {8}{'de}
    {9}{'da}
    {10}{'da}
    {20}{'de}
    {30}{'da}
    {40}{'da}
    {50}{'de}
    {60}{'da}
    {70}{'de}
    {80}{'de}
    {90}{'da}
    {100}{'de}
    {1000}{'de}
   }
   {
    \turksuf_complex:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \turksuf_suffix:n { V }

\cs_new:Npn \turksuf_complex:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 10 } = 0 }
   { \turksuf_complex_ten:n { #1 } }
   { \turksuf_nonzero:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 10 } } }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \turksuf_complex_ten:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 100 } = 0 }
   { \turksuf_complex_hundred:n { #1 } }
   { \turksuf_nonzero:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 100 } } }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \turksuf_complex_hundred:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 1000 } = 0 }
   { \turksuf_complex_thousand:n { #1 } }
   { 'de }%{ \turksuf_nonzero:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 1000 } } }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \turksuf_complex_thousand:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 10000 } = 0 }
   { \turksuf_complex_tenthousand:n { #1 } }
   { 'de }%{ \turksuf_nonzero:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 10000 } } }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \turksuf_complex_tenthousand:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 100000 } = 0 }
   { \turksuf_complex_hundredthousand:n { #1 } }
   { 'de }%{ \turksuf_nonzero:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 100000 } } }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \turksuf_complex_hundredthousand:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 1000000 } = 0 }
   { \turksuf_complex_million:n { #1 } }
   { 'da }%{ \turksuf_nonzero:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 1000000 } } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand\test{m}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { #1 }
   { ##1\turkishsuffix{##1}\par }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the test

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{5}
\test{300}
\end{multicols}

\setcounter{figure}{12}
\begin{figure}
\caption{X}\label{A}
\end{figure}
\figurename~\turkishref{A}.

1234\turkishsuffix{1234}\\
1320\turkishsuffix{1320}\\
1330\turkishsuffix{1330}\\
1000\turkishsuffix{1000}\\
1003\turkishsuffix{1003}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{3}
\subsection{B}\label{B}

Subsection~\turkishref{B}

\end{document}
```

I show only the last lines with the reference to the figure and the following test cases.

**NOTE** Support for "composite numbers" has been added. Moreover, one has `\turkishref*` that calls `\ref*` instead of `\ref` (of course `hyperref` is needed for this to work).

[image]

---

Here is a packaged version of the code. Save as `turkref.sty` in any place searched by TeX programs, for instance in

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/turkref/
```

on GNU/Linux systems or

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/turkref/
```

for Mac OS X.

```
\RequirePackage{expl3,xparse}
\ProvidesExplPackage{turkref}{2014/12/11}{0.1}{Turkish suffix for ref}

\@ifpackagelater { expl3 } { 2012/11/21 }
 { }
 {
  \PackageError { turkref } { Support~package~expl3~too~old }
   {
    You~need~to~update~your~installation~of~the~bundles~'l3kernel'~and~
    'l3packages'.\MessageBreak
    Loading~turkref~will~abort!
   }
  \tex_endinput:D
 }

\RequirePackage{refcount}

% User commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\turkishref}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\ref*{#2}}{\ref{#2}}
  \turksuf_suffix_get:n { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\turkishsuffix}{m}
 {
  \turksuf_suffix:n { #1 }
 }

% Variables
\seq_new:N \l__turksuf_ref_seq
\tl_new:N \l__turksuf_ref_tl

\cs_new_eq:NN \turksuf_getrefnumber:n \getrefnumber

% Functions
\cs_new_protected:Npn \turksuf_suffix_get:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l__turksuf_ref_seq { . } { \turksuf_getrefnumber:n { #1 } }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__turksuf_ref_seq \l__turksuf_ref_tl
  \turksuf_suffix:V \l__turksuf_ref_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }

\cs_new:Npn \turksuf_suffix:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 == 0 } { 'da } { \__turksuf_nonzero:n { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__turksuf_nonzero:n #1
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {1}{'de}
    {2}{'de}
    {3}{'te}
    {4}{'te}
    {5}{'te}
    {6}{'da}
    {7}{'de}
    {8}{'de}
    {9}{'da}
    {10}{'da}
    {20}{'de}
    {30}{'da}
    {40}{'da}
    {50}{'de}
    {60}{'da}
    {70}{'de}
    {80}{'de}
    {90}{'da}
    {100}{'de}
    {1000}{'de}
   }
   {
    \__turksuf_complex:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \turksuf_suffix:n { V }

\cs_new:Npn \__turksuf_complex:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 10 } = 0 }
   { \__turksuf_complex_ten:n { #1 } }
   { \__turksuf_nonzero:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 10 } } }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__turksuf_complex_ten:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 100 } = 0 }
   { \__turksuf_complex_hundred:n { #1 } }
   { \__turksuf_nonzero:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 100 } } }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__turksuf_complex_hundred:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 1000 } = 0 }
   { \__turksuf_complex_thousand:n { #1 } }
   { 'de }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__turksuf_complex_thousand:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 10000 } = 0 }
   { \__turksuf_complex_tenthousand:n { #1 } }
   { 'de }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__turksuf_complex_tenthousand:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 100000 } = 0 }
   { \__turksuf_complex_hundredthousand:n { #1 } }
   { 'de }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__turksuf_complex_hundredthousand:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 1000000 } = 0 }
   { \__turksuf_complex_million:n { #1 } }
   { 'da }
 }
```

Now the test document can be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{turkref} % <--- load the package

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Just for testing not needed in real documents
\NewDocumentCommand\test{m}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { #1 }
   { ##1\turkishsuffix{##1}\par }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the test

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{5}
\test{300}
\end{multicols}

\setcounter{figure}{12}
\begin{figure}
\caption{X}\label{A}
\end{figure}
\figurename~\turkishref{A}.

1234\turkishsuffix{1234}\\
1320\turkishsuffix{1320}\\
1330\turkishsuffix{1330}\\
1000\turkishsuffix{1000}\\
1003\turkishsuffix{1003}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{3}
\subsection{B}\label{B}

Subsection~\turkishref{B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It gives an error at line 17 saying that: `Illegal parameter number in definition of \turksuf_suffix_get:n:    ...turksuf_ref_seq { . } { \getrefnumber { #2 ...`. How can I fix it?

Comment: @petrichor Sorry, a copy-paste error; the `#2` should be `#1`; I'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: It works perfect now with the composite numbers. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey @egreg could you please take a look at this post? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646940/error-in-style-file-used-to-use-turkish-additions

Answer (score 4):

This tweaks into the package `fmtcount` and provides the numeric ordinals for `turkish` language.

First, save the following code as `fc-turkish.tex` (for example, the name does not matter). The official name inside the package `fmtcount` would be different, but I don't want to use the official one since this is not an official file of the package.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@OT@do#1#2#3#4#5#6#7\@OT@enddo{%
\ifcase0#1 % ~0
  \ifx\relax#2\relax% 0
    \def\@OT@suf{da}%
  \else
    \ifcase#2 % ~00
      \ifx0#3% ~000
        \ifx0#4% ~0000
          \ifx0#5% ~00000
            \ifx0#6% ~000000
              \def\@OT@suf{da}%
            \else % ~x00000
              \def\@OT@suf{de}%
            \fi
          \else % ~x0000
            \def\@OT@suf{de}%
          \fi
        \else % ~x000
          \def\@OT@suf{de}%
        \fi
      \else % ~x00
        \def\@OT@suf{de}%
      \fi
    \or% ~10
      \def\@OT@suf{da}%
    \or% ~20
      \def\@OT@suf{de}%
    \or% ~30
      \def\@OT@suf{da}%
    \or% ~40
      \def\@OT@suf{da}%
    \or% ~50
      \def\@OT@suf{de}%
    \or% ~60
      \def\@OT@suf{da}%
    \or% ~70
      \def\@OT@suf{de}%
    \or% ~80
      \def\@OT@suf{de}%
    \or% ~90
      \def\@OT@suf{da}%
    \fi
  \fi
\or% ~1
  \def\@OT@suf{de}%
\or% ~2
  \def\@OT@suf{de}%
\or% ~3
  \def\@OT@suf{te}%
\or% ~4
  \def\@OT@suf{te}%
\or% ~5
  \def\@OT@suf{te}%
\or% ~6
  \def\@OT@suf{da}%
\or% ~7
  \def\@OT@suf{de}%
\or% ~8
  \def\@OT@suf{de}%
\or% ~9
  \def\@OT@suf{da}%
\fi
}
\def\@OT@rev#1#2\revA#3\revB{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi{#1#3}{\@OT@rev#2\revA#1#3\revB}}
\newcommand{\@ordinalMturkish}[1]{%
  \@orgargctr=#1\relax
  \@ordinalctr=#1%
  \edef\@OT@str{\the\@ordinalctr}%
  \edef\@OT@str{\expandafter\@OT@rev\@OT@str\revA\revB}%
  \expandafter\@OT@do\@OT@str\relax\relax\relax\relax\relax\relax\@OT@enddo
  \the\@orgargctr\fmtord{'\@OT@suf}%
}
\def\ordref#1{%
  \edef\@OD@ref{\csname r@#1\endcsname\relax}%
  \edef\@OD@num{\expandafter\@firstoftwo\@OD@ref}%
  \ifx\@OD@num\relax
    \@orgargctr0%
  \else
    \expandafter\@orgargctr0\@OD@num
  \fi
  \@ordinalMturkish\@orgargctr
}
\let\@ordinalFturkish=\@ordinalMturkish
\makeatother
```

Then, you can use the package `fmtcount` with `turkish`. Test document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[level]{fmtcount}
\input{fc-turkish.tex}
\def\fmtord#1{#1}
\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\section{First}

\section{Hello World!}\label{sec2s}

In \ordref{sec2s} section, there is a test of package functionality:

\raggedright\ttfamily

\ordinal{section}
\loop
\ifnum\value{section}<1000
\refstepcounter{section}
\ordinal{section}
\repeat

\loop
\ifnum\value{section}<100000
\addtocounter{section}{1030}
\ordinal{section}
\repeat

\setcounter{section}{0}

\loop
\ifnum\value{section}<1000000
\addtocounter{section}{100000}
\ordinal{section}
\repeat

\end{document}
```

I apologize for not commenting the code. I'm actually not sure how I would comment it. Part is taken from `fc-english.def` and another part is a bunch of tests to get the right suffix. Only a small note: the macro `\OT@do` is fed the number to be typeset, but written reversed, so the least significant digit is got as `#1`. The macro `\ordref` won't work with nested numbers (`2` is ok, `2.4` is not).

Comment: It gave an error for my case: `Line 18: Undefined control sequence:    <argument> ...e c@section\endcsname }{\@fc@ordstr :    \ordinal{section}`. I am using Miktex on Windows and generating via pdflatex. I saved the file with the name you gave and trying to compile the second file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rookie's approach to the problem (The rookie is me). It doesn't use LaTeX3. It handles more suffix types. I made it into a simple package. It requires packages `etoolbox`, `xparse`, `xstring`, and `refcount`

### Usage notes on package `reftr`

```
reftr package replaces \ref command by default. 
If you don't want this behaviour simply comment the last line of the package.
Then you will have to use \reftr command for suffixed cross references.
This package should also work with composite numbers (such as "2.12").

reftr package also defines \trnumdecorator macro for suffixing numbers.

Usage of \ref (or \reftr if not replaced):

To produce only the label number (original \ref behavior):
\ref{(label name)} 

To produce label number with a suffix:
\ref{label name}{suffix}

suffix should be defined as if it was for number "1". Allowed suffixes are:
 - de
 - den
 - e
 - i
 - in

Examples (assuming the figure with label "fig:figure3" is the third figure):

\ref{fig:figure3}       %This will output "3"
\ref{fig:figure3}{de}   %This will output "3'te"
\ref{fig:figure3}{den}  %This will output "3'ten"
\ref{fig:figure3}{e}    %This will output "3'e"
\ref{fig:figure3}{i}    %This will output "3'ü"
\ref{fig:figure3}{in}   %This will output "3'ün"

Errors:

If \ref{}{} comes accross a number that it can't handle it will produce "3'??"
If a wrong suffix is input it will produce "'?unknwnSfx"

\ref{fig:figure3}{ün} %This will output "3'?unknwnSfx"

Usage of \trnumdecorator:

\trnumdecorator{argument-that-ends-with-number}{suffix}

suffix should be defined as if it was for number "1". Allowed suffixes are:
 - de
 - den
 - e
 - i
 - in

The stared version \trnumdecorator* will only produce the suffix

Example:

\trnumdecorator{blabla20}{in}   %This will output "blabla20'nin"
\trnumdecorator*{blabla20}{in}  %This will output "'nin"

Note: \trnumdecorator* is what \ref uses for suffixing numbers
```

### Package Code

*Don't be harsh on me, I am a newbie*

```
\ProvidesPackage{reftr}


\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{refcount}

\csdef{trsuf1de}{de}
\csdef{trsuf2de}{de}
\csdef{trsuf3de}{te}
\csdef{trsuf4de}{te}
\csdef{trsuf5de}{te}
\csdef{trsuf6de}{da}
\csdef{trsuf7de}{de}
\csdef{trsuf8de}{de}
\csdef{trsuf9de}{da}
\csdef{trsuf10de}{da}
\csdef{trsuf20de}{de}
\csdef{trsuf30de}{da}
\csdef{trsuf40de}{ta}
\csdef{trsuf50de}{de}
\csdef{trsuf60de}{ta}
\csdef{trsuf70de}{te}
\csdef{trsuf80de}{de}
\csdef{trsuf90de}{da}
\csdef{trsuf100de}{de}
\csdef{trsuf1000de}{de}

\csdef{trsuf1den}{den}
\csdef{trsuf2den}{den}
\csdef{trsuf3den}{ten}
\csdef{trsuf4den}{ten}
\csdef{trsuf5den}{ten}
\csdef{trsuf6den}{dan}
\csdef{trsuf7den}{den}
\csdef{trsuf8den}{den}
\csdef{trsuf9den}{dan}
\csdef{trsuf10den}{dan}
\csdef{trsuf20den}{den}
\csdef{trsuf30den}{dan}
\csdef{trsuf40den}{tan}
\csdef{trsuf50den}{den}
\csdef{trsuf60den}{tan}
\csdef{trsuf70den}{ten}
\csdef{trsuf80den}{den}
\csdef{trsuf90den}{dan}
\csdef{trsuf100den}{den}
\csdef{trsuf1000den}{den}

\csdef{trsuf1e}{e}
\csdef{trsuf2e}{ye}
\csdef{trsuf3e}{e}
\csdef{trsuf4e}{e}
\csdef{trsuf5e}{e}
\csdef{trsuf6e}{ya}
\csdef{trsuf7e}{ye}
\csdef{trsuf8e}{e}
\csdef{trsuf9e}{a}
\csdef{trsuf10e}{a}
\csdef{trsuf20e}{ye}
\csdef{trsuf30e}{a}
\csdef{trsuf40e}{a}
\csdef{trsuf50e}{ye}
\csdef{trsuf60e}{a}
\csdef{trsuf70e}{e}
\csdef{trsuf80e}{e}
\csdef{trsuf90e}{a}
\csdef{trsuf100e}{e}
\csdef{trsuf1000e}{e}

\csdef{trsuf1i}{i}
\csdef{trsuf2i}{yi}
\csdef{trsuf3i}{ü}
\csdef{trsuf4i}{ü}
\csdef{trsuf5i}{i}
\csdef{trsuf6i}{yı}
\csdef{trsuf7i}{yi}
\csdef{trsuf8i}{i}
\csdef{trsuf9i}{u}
\csdef{trsuf10i}{u}
\csdef{trsuf20i}{yi}
\csdef{trsuf30i}{u}
\csdef{trsuf40i}{ı}
\csdef{trsuf50i}{yi}
\csdef{trsuf60i}{ı}
\csdef{trsuf70i}{i}
\csdef{trsuf80i}{i}
\csdef{trsuf90i}{ı}
\csdef{trsuf100i}{ü}
\csdef{trsuf1000i}{i}

\csdef{trsuf1in}{in}
\csdef{trsuf2in}{nin}
\csdef{trsuf3in}{ün}
\csdef{trsuf4in}{ün}
\csdef{trsuf5in}{in}
\csdef{trsuf6in}{nın}
\csdef{trsuf7in}{nin}
\csdef{trsuf8in}{in}
\csdef{trsuf9in}{un}
\csdef{trsuf10in}{un}
\csdef{trsuf20in}{nin}
\csdef{trsuf30in}{un}
\csdef{trsuf40in}{ın}
\csdef{trsuf50in}{nin}
\csdef{trsuf60in}{ın}
\csdef{trsuf70in}{in}
\csdef{trsuf80in}{in}
\csdef{trsuf90in}{ın}
\csdef{trsuf100in}{ün}
\csdef{trsuf1000in}{in}

\NewDocumentCommand \trnumdecorator {s m m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}{}{#2}%
    \csdef{rtLstDgt}{?}%    
    \IfEndWith{#2}{1}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{1}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{2}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{2}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{3}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{3}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{4}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{4}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{5}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{5}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{6}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{6}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{7}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{7}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{8}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{8}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{9}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{9}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{10}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{10}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{20}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{20}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{30}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{30}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{40}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{40}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{50}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{50}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{60}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{60}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{70}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{70}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{80}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{80}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{90}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{90}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{00}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{100}}{}%
    \IfEndWith{#2}{000}{\csdef{rtLstDgt}{1000}}{}%
    %\IfEq{\csuse{rtLstDgt}}{?}{'??}{'\csuse{trsuf\csuse{rtLstDgt}#3}}%Comment the line below and uncomment this one if you don't want ?unknwnSfx to be produced
    \IfEq{\csuse{rtLstDgt}}{?}{'??}{'\ifcsdef{trsuf\csuse{rtLstDgt}#3}    {\csuse{trsuf\csuse{rtLstDgt}#3}}{?unknwnSfx}}%       
}%

\let\oldref=\ref %this is added to allow converting \ref into \reftr

\NewDocumentCommand \reftr {m g}{%
    \oldref{#1}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{%
        \trnumdecorator*{\getrefnumber{#1}}{#2}%        
    }%
}%

\let\ref=\reftr %this line makes \ref work as \reftr
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98366/105447) leveraging the flexibility of `zref` (through `zref-clever`), so that there's no need to use dedicated reference commands. We build a `zref` property which includes the suffix, and then we can make references like any other ones. (With all the goodies of using standard reference commands).

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{turkref} % by 'egreg': https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98366/105447

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcDeclareLanguage{turkish}
\zcLanguageSetup{turkish}{
  type=section,
    name-sg=Bölüm, % ???
  type=figure,
    name-sg=Şekil, % ???
}

% creating the reference property
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{turkishref}{%
  \@currentlabel\turkishsuffix{\arabic{\@currentcounter}}}
\zref@addprop{main}{turkishref}
\makeatother

% Set default ref property to turkishref
\zcsetup{ref=turkishref}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{figure}{6}
\begin{figure}
\caption{X}
\zlabel{A}
\end{figure}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{14}
\subsection{B}
\zlabel{B}

\zcref{A}

\zcref{B}

\end{document}
```

[image]