# Long space in italic format

Tags: spacing

MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
120 kHz ’e

\textit{120 kHz ’e}
\end{document}
```

and output,

[image]

Sometimes this red line is getting longer. Why not red line is short? I didn't find solution about this question. Does anyone know how to fix it? (My english text changeable)

[image]

Comment: Instead of using a space " ", use `\,` (say). See [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)

Comment: Units should never be italicized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(SI) Units have to be typed according to certain rules. Don't worry about them if you don't know what are the rules, use `siunitx`. Then all the spacing and fonts will come right. *Never* use italics for units as already told by egreg.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{120}{\kHz}\,’e

!!!Don't do this!!!
\textit{\SI{120}{\kHz}\,’e}   %% Don't do this don't.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the space before `'e` should be absent or thin (`\,`); I believe it's a “declension suffix”.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. BTW what is declension suffix? Reading now :-) Thanks and I have added a thin space.

Comment: Possibly something analog to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98330/changing-the-suffix-according-to-the-figure-number I'm not sure if “declension” is the right term.

Comment: @egreg Oh, now I am slowly getting it. Then I think it should be `120'e kHz` IMO.  Thanks for letting me learn some Latin things. :-)

Comment: That's Turkish. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Oh No!. The word (declension) was coined with  latin. Again thanks for holding me from stumbling :-)